# How to import a scss file inside a scss class

Tags: css, angular, sass

I want to add a different theme when i add "dark-theme" class to body. My implementation looks like this:

```
@import '../../../../node_modules/angular-grids/styles/material.scss';

.app-dark {
  @import '../../../../node_modules/angular-grids/styles/material-dark.scss';
}
```

Without any luck. Any clue on how to do this?

Comment: `@import '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids/styles/material-dark.css';`

Comment: no by default, it should load different theme, when i add that class to body theme should change

Comment: did you check this? https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10868/dynamic-theme-change

Comment: You can't do it only with css

Comment: i think you didn't understand my query.  can we able to import scss file inside scss class

Comment: you could nest a Sass @import inside of a rule of a parent file

Comment: @demkovych, do you have any workaround?

Comment: create a mixin in the other file, import the file, and use the mixin inside the parent class?

Comment: @Thatkookooguy, Can you please share some documentation or anything else since i am new to sass

Comment: sure. I'll add an answer

Comment: @kumaresan_sd added an answer. hope this helped! please don't forget to mark the answer and upvote if it did :-)

Answer (score 5):

There are two methods in order to do that. Both of them include mixins.

### meta.load-css

The [`sass:meta` feature](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/meta#load-css) gives the ability to do what you want.

Say you have this scss file with a theme:

```scss
//theme/_code.scss
$border-contrast: false !default;

code {
  background-color: #6b717f;
  color: #d2e1dd;
  @if $border-contrast {
    border-color: #dadbdf;
  }
}
```

you can include that code inside another scss file like so:

```scss
// other-theme.scss
@use "sass:meta";

body.dark {
  @include meta.load-css("theme/code",
      $with: ("border-contrast": true));
}
```

This will result in the following css:

```css
body.dark code {
  background-color: #6b717f;
  color: #d2e1dd;
  border-color: #dadbdf;
}
```

You can read more about this feature here

### old fashioned mixin

But you can do basically the same thing if you use [mixin and include](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin).

So, let's say you have this class you want to import into another class:

```scss
.title {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

And another sass file with another theme:

```scss
.dark-theme {
  .title {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

You can use a scss mixin and import it into both files:

#### mixin.scss

```scss
@mixin shared-items() {
  .title {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

then, in the theme files:

#### white-theme.scss

```scss
@import './mixin.scss';

/* will be included as is without a parent class */
@include shared-items;
```

#### dark-theme.scss

```scss
@import './mixin.scss';

/* will be included inside the dark-theme class */
.dark-theme {
  .title {
    color: white;
  }

  @include shared-items;
}
```

this will generate this css:

```css
.title {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dark-theme {
  .title { color: white; }
  .title {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

Notice that you can also pass parameters to mixin and use them as functions.
So you can easily pass colors and use them with your theme variables.

for example:

```scss
/* an example of giving a color to a placeholder mixin: */
@mixin nk-placeholder($color: #C4C4CC) {
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: $color;
        font: inherit;
    }
    &::-moz-placeholder {
        color: $color;
        font: inherit;
    }
    &:-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: $color;
        font: inherit;
    }
    &:-moz-placeholder {
        color: $color;
        font: inherit;
    }
    &::placeholder {
        color: $color;
        font: inherit;
    }
}

/* same thing as above */
@mixin shared-items($text-color: black) {
  .title {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: $text-color;
  }
}


.white-theme {
  @include shared-items;
}

.dark-theme {
  @include shared-items(white);
}
```

Comment: HI @thatkookooguy, thanks..but i requirement in litltle different...1st i have one class called "dark" i have to import my entire scss file inside that class when i add that class `dark` to `body` then only styles get included

Comment: Not sure I understand. Hop on [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206788/talk-about-how-to-import-a-scss-file-inside-a-scss-class) and explain in details what's missing for your use-case

Comment: You can take that entire file with all the SCSS, wrap it in a `mixin` function, and import it twice: once as is (which will replace the original SCSS file) and one inside the `dark` class to add the same CSS inside the `dark` class. It sounds to me like this is the same use-case. No?

Comment: i have created sample and adeed my requiremt in this sample..https://github.com/kumaresan-subramani/anguular-scss...please provided any suggestion

Comment: @kumaresan_sd ok, now I understand the situation a bit better. I added another option that uses `sass:meta` and should allow you to import a file like that (that you don't control) into your own class.

Comment: Can you do this in my github if you can please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59966421/gulp-sass-wont-compile-and-include-all-imported-files

Comment: @kumaresan_sd I'm here to help you implement what you need, but I'm not here to do it instead of you. I pointed you to the available solutions and gave you examples. What more is missing for you to be able to progress with your problem? maybe you need to define your question better. [writing your question better also might be a better solution than opening a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59966421/gulp-sass-wont-compile-and-include-all-imported-files)

Comment: I don't know why this is posted here as an answer to the question. The question is clearly how to conditionally @import two different css files from node modules. Nowhere in your answer do you address this problem. Instead you are talking about something else. Additionally, when you want to demonstrate a concept, you should keep your example as short and simple as possible.